# Accessing data from a json array in python JSONDecodeError at /get/

Tags: python, django

My response looks like:

```
[
 {"_id":"5f6060d0d279373c0017447d","name":"Faizan","email":"faizan@test.com"}
]
```

I want to get the name in python. I am tryting:

```
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
```

The error I am getting is:
JSONDecodeError at /get/

Comment: what is response.text content, also post full trackback

Comment: Are you saying to use response.text() instead of response.json()  ?

Comment: no, I am saying to DEBUG your code and look into what does it return by looking into response.text, also while posting question doing the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and posting full traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might help you

```
import requests
import json
dburl = 'https://postman-9e13.restdb.io/rest/contact'
headers = {'x-apikey': '7267cbb3c251a01dd8563ca447194e78af67d', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
params = {"name":"Faizan","email":"faizan@test.com"}
r = requests.get(dburl, params=params, headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

after seeing the result, you can pass to your templates like this

```
geodata = response.json() 
return render(request, 'main/get.html', { 'name': geodata[0]['name'] })
```

or you can change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you shared is correct, however the problem might be with the URL.

```
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
```

Here, .json() only works for the response which is in the JSON format only. If it is showing that error that means your URL returning the HTML document.

Comment: My url is:
https://postman-9e13.restdb.io/rest/contact?q={"name":"Faizan","email":"faizan@test.com"}
Which return a json

Comment: postman-9e13.restdb.io/rest/contact?q={"name":"Faizan","email":"faizan@test.com"} when i'm visiting to this link it showing me this line **No access. Code 001** , you could just use _response.text_ to see what your URL is returning.

Comment: Strange thing! I am using restdb.io and the link is only working in the browser in which I have log in to the site restdb.io

Comment: did you try using **response.text** ?

Comment: yes, I get the error:  'str' object is not callable

Comment: i guess you're using response.text() which is supported in javascript not in python, in python you need to write **response.text** not **response.text()**

Comment: yes, you are right. Now, by using response.text I got the error No access. Code 001

Comment: I think there is some authentication issue with the url

Comment: you might need api key to be added in the URL to access its data.

Comment: I have added api key in the url and it is working in the browser but giving the same error "No access. Code 001" when I use it in django.

Comment: can you share your Django code where you're using this

Comment: This is my view:
response = requests.get('https://postman-9e13.restdb.io/rest/contact?q={"name":"Faizan","email":"faizan@test.com"}&key":"7267cbb3c251a01dd8563ca447194e78af67d"')
geodata = response.json()
return render(request, 'main/get.html', {
'name': geodata['name']
})

and this is get.html:
{% extends 'main/header.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <p>Your ip returned name is <strong>{{ name }}</strong>, </p>
{% endblock %}

Comment: I have answered your query, check if it helps you